# Grails fails to parse request when content type is specified during post

Tags: grails

Using `wget` I make two posts to the same url with xml in the body.  The first works.  The second has the content type specified and it does not work.  Why is this and how do I get grails to parse the request even when the content type is specified?

first wget:

```
wget http://localhost:8080/myApp/myMoeView/save --post-file=xmltest.xml
```

Grails logs (notice the "parsed params"):

```
2014-02-27 18:44:05,465 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] INFO  httplogger.DefaultHttpLogger  - << #3425 POST http://localhost:8080/myApp/mrMoeView/save
2014-02-27 18:44:05,465 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] INFO  httplogger.DefaultHttpLogger  - << #3425 headers [Cookie: JSESSIONID=D5B2399D6FFB800130E826DCD7DB0C37]
2014-02-27 18:44:05,465 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] INFO  httplogger.DefaultHttpLogger  - << #3425 body: ''
2014-02-27 18:44:05,491 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] INFO  httplogger.DefaultHttpLogger  - << #3425 dispatched to mrMoeView/save with parsed params ['<?xml version':'{"1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><mrMoeView><absoluteTolerance>1.004</absoluteTolerance><endTime>0</endTime><id>4187</id><lastModified>2014-01-07 00:00:00.000 PST</lastModified><modelRealizationId>1193</modelRealizationId><mrMoeId>4187</mrMoeId><mrMoeName>Default MOE from Model 2140</mrMoeName><relativeTolerance>1e-4</relativeTolerance><startTime>0</startTime></mrMoeView>
```

second wget:

```
wget http://localhost:8080/myApp/mrMoeView/save --post-file=xmltest.xml --header="Content-Type:application/xml"
```

Grails logs (notice no parsed params, and the body has all the xml):

```
2014-02-27 18:46:27,291 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] INFO  httplogger.DefaultHttpLogger  - << #3427 POST http://localhost:8080/processdb/mrMoeView/save
2014-02-27 18:46:27,291 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] INFO  httplogger.DefaultHttpLogger  - << #3427 headers [Cookie: JSESSIONID=B1FAAB54422AC7F1E243D4CE68C72B77]
2014-02-27 18:46:27,291 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] INFO  httplogger.DefaultHttpLogger  - << #3427 body: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><mrMoeView><absoluteTolerance>1.004</absoluteTolerance><endTime>0</endTime><id>4187</id><lastModified>2014-01-07 00:00:00.000 PST</lastModified><modelRealizationId>1193</modelRealizationId><mrMoeId>4187</mrMoeId><mrMoeName>Default MOE from Model 2140</mrMoeName><relativeTolerance>1e-4</relativeTolerance><startTime>0</startTime></mrMoeView>'
2014-02-27 18:46:27,320 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] INFO  httplogger.DefaultHttpLogger  - << #3427 dispatched to mrMoeView/save with parsed params [].
```

Grails version 2.3.5

**UPDATE**

UrlMapping:

```
class UrlMappings {

static mappings = {
    "/$controller/$action?/$id?"(parseRequest:true){
        constraints {
            // apply constraints here
        }
    }

    "/"(view:"/index")
    "500"(view:'/error')
}
}
```

Comment: with content type specified you will receive the body as request body instead of parsed params. You should be able to do `request.XML` in action to get the request body.

Comment: I think you can use `parseRequest: true` in UrlMapping to achieve what you need.

Comment: I already have `parseRequest: true`... I'll update the question with my UrlMapping.

Comment: How do I get the body into a domain model?  With params I just do `new DomainModel(params.mrMoeView)`

Comment: Okay, so the question about getting the body to a domain model is not what my original question asked... the answer is `bindData(domainModel,request.XML)`.  However, if you'll put your answer into an answer instead of the comments and provide a reference, I'll accept it, @dmahapatro

Comment: You should be able to just bind the body directly to domain obj without bindData. `def save(MyDomain abc){••} ` should automatically bind the request body as long as u have a valid id in the body otherwise you would get a null object. Have u tried it yet?

Comment: Whoa!  That's sooo cool!  How come I haven't come across that in the Grails docs.  So yeah, that works.

Comment: Yeap, that works and that's more what I want to do anyway. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: This is a feature in Grails 2.3.* brought in after revamping the whole data binding framework in Grails. Glad it was helpful. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With content type specified content will be received as part of request body instead of parsed params.

Body can be accessed as `request.XML` in action. Going through the comments, we found out the usage of a older way to `bindData`. With Grails 2.3.*, the request payload can be directly bound to a domain object provided the body has a valid `id` as :

```
def save(MyDomain abc){
    //use abc.name
}
```

If a valid id is not present in request body then domain object will be null inside the action.

@[Data binding](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#dataBinding).

Comment: Okay, I had such a hard time finding this because it is actually in the command objects section of the documentation: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#commandObjects