# How to limit properties bound when using domain model as a command object

Tags: grails

This really powerful feature of grails

```
def save(MyDomain model) {
  model.save()
  render ''
}
```

will parse the request body or params, run `MyDomain.get(id)`, fill in the properties from the request body or params and save.  That's a lot for this little bit of code.

How do I limit the properties to bind to `model`?  Say I have an `accountBalance` property that is read only and I don't want a malicious user to be able to change their account balance.

Also, I want to have multiple actions that save a different subset of properties of `MyDomain`... say one action could be for a bank teller user that is making a deposit for the account holder.  In this case the teller should be able to set `accountBalance` but not `password`.

I realize that an actual banking app wouldn't work like this, it's just an example.

I had other problems that led me to use command objects to bind data (see [Grails fails to parse request when content type is specified during post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22085212/grails-fails-to-parse-request-when-content-type-is-specified-during-post)).  Any solution would also have to address that post.  I imagine if the solution uses command objects then it will work, but if command objects aren't in the solution, then the request body problem has to be addressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have not tried on an actual domain class but can you try using [`bindData`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/bindData.html) instead of implicitly binding where you can particularly specify which property to exclude?

```
def save() {
  //params - A Map of source parameters
  //It can be params or any other representation of request body
  //request.JSON, request.XML

  MyDomain model = MyDomain.get(params.id?.toLong())

  bindData(model, params, [exclude: ['accountBalance']])

  model.save()
  render ''
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but this doesn't address the problem where the params are not parsed from the xml in request body.  See the other post I reference in the question.

Comment: Doesn't `request.XML` give a similar map as `params`?

Comment: Yes it does, I didn't know you could use `request.XML`.  I didn't see that anywhere in the docs and I didn't realize it's a map that (as the docs for `bindData` say any map can be used).

Comment: you've been a great help in my grails learning!! The solution works for most of my cases, but it doesn't work in the case of a composite id.  Say the id of `MyDomain` is of type `MyCompositeId` with fields `firstName` and `lastName`.  When I call bindData it doesn't bind any data!  I'm posting a new question for this issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22774801/how-to-bind-data-with-binddata-in-grails-with-request-xml-that-contains-a-nested

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at the [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/theWebLayer.html#dataBinding) about binding. There is a lot of information, in particular the section about security which is similar to your concerns. Looking at the fact [bindData()](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/ref/Controllers/bindData.html) allows you include/exclude properties you should be able to write any variation of your binding you need.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I've already read this documentation and would love to use `bindData`, but I cannot because the params do not have the properties as they should.  See the link in the OP about this.