# How to bind data with bindData in grails with request XML that contains a nested class

Tags: grails

I have xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<myModel id="mybiz.MyModelIdId@36491253">
  <id>
    <class>mybiz.MyModelId</class>
    <idPart1>1292</idPart1>
    <idPart2>somestring</idPart2>
  </id>
  <otherStuff>233</otherStuff>
</myModel>
```

Now, I would like to use bind data like this:

```
def save() {
    MyModel model = new MyModel()
    bindData(model,request.XML)
    log.info("other stuff = "+model.otherStuff)
    log.info("idPart1 = "+model.id.idPart1)
    log.info("idPart2 = "+model.id.idPart2)
```

but I get all `null`s as output, so it hasn't worked.  However, when I use the following code

```
def grailsWebDataBinder
def save() {
    MyModel model = new MyModel()
    grailsWebDataBinder.bind model, request.XML
    log.info("other stuff = "+model.otherStuff)
    log.info("idPart1 = "+model.id.idPart1)
    log.info("idPart2 = "+model.id.idPart2)
```

I get `233` as output then a null pointer exception for the `id` attribute.

What am I doing wrong?

(I'm using grails 2.3.7)

**UPDATE**

Here are the domain classes (with composite id)

MyModel.java:

```
@XmlRootElement
@Entity
@Table(name="MY_MODEL"
    ,schema="MY_SCHEMA"
)
public class MyModel implements java.io.Serializable {

    private MyModelId id;
    private BigDecimal otherStuff;

    public MyModel() {
    }

    public MyModel(MyModelId id, BigDecimal otherStuff) {
        this.id = id;
        this.otherStuff = otherStuff;
    }

    @EmbeddedId
    @AttributeOverrides( {
        @AttributeOverride(name="idPart1", column=@Column(name="ID_PART1", nullable=false, precision=22, scale=0) ), 
        @AttributeOverride(name="idPart2", column=@Column(name="ID_PART2", nullable=false, length=240) ) } )
    public MyModelId getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(MyModelId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name="OTHER_STUFF", nullable=false, precision=22, scale=0)
    public BigDecimal getOtherStuff() {
        return this.otherStuff;
    }

    public void setOtherStuff(BigDecimal otherStuff) {
        this.otherStuff = otherStuff;
    }

}
```

MyModelId.java:

```
@XmlRootElement
@Embeddable
public class MyModelId implements java.io.Serializable {

    private BigDecimal idPart1;
    private String idPart2;

    public MyModelId() {
    }

    public MyModelId(BigDecimal idPart1, String idPart2) {
       this.idPart1 = idPart1;
       this.idPart2 = idPart2;
    }

    @Column(name="ID_PART1", nullable=false, precision=22, scale=0)
    public BigDecimal getIdPart1() {
        return this.idPart1;
    }

    public void setIdPart1(BigDecimal idPart1) {
        this.idPart1 = idPart1;
    }

    @Column(name="ID_PART2", nullable=false, length=240)
    public String getIdPart2() {
        return this.idPart2;
    }

    public void setIdPart2(String idPart2) {
        this.idPart2 = idPart2;
    }

   public boolean equals(Object other) {
         if ( (this == other ) ) return true;
         if ( (other == null ) ) return false;
         if ( !(other instanceof MyModelId) ) return false;
         MyModelId castOther = ( MyModelId ) other; 

         return ( (this.getIdPart1()==castOther.getIdPart1()) || ( this.getIdPart1()!=null && castOther.getIdPart1()!=null && this.getIdPart1().equals(castOther.getIdPart1()) ) )
 && ( (this.getIdPart2()==castOther.getIdPart2()) || ( this.getIdPart2()!=null && castOther.getIdPart2()!=null && this.getIdPart2().equals(castOther.getIdPart2()) ) );
   }

   public int hashCode() {
         int result = 17;

         result = 37 * result + ( getIdPart1() == null ? 0 : this.getIdPart1().hashCode() );
         result = 37 * result + ( getIdPart2() == null ? 0 : this.getIdPart2().hashCode() );
         return result;
   }   

}
```

Comment: Also add `MyModel` domain class to get the full picture.

Comment: Hmmm... that will be difficult.  I changed the names to protect the innocent and the actual domain class is a Java POJO generated by a reverse map of the database using hibernate.  I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

The following works

```
def id
id = new MyModelId()
bindData(id,request.XML.id)
MyModel model = MyModel.get(id)
bindData(model,request.XML)
```