# Trying to determine the origin of this method's parameter

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails, groovy

In the following snippet, where is the `awardTypes` coming from? The URL in question: `http://localhost:8080/awardTypes/edit/1`. I need help understanding the request flow.

`/mgs/grails-app/controllers/com/mgs/AwardTypesController.groovy`

```
class AwardTypesController {
   ...
   def edit(AwardTypes awardTypes) {
        respond awardTypes
    }
    ...
}
```

`/mgs/grails-app/conf/hibernate.cfg.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <mapping resource="AwardTypes.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

`/mgs/grails-app/conf/AwardTypes.hbm.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 14-Oct-2015 10:13:15 PM by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1.Final -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.mgs.AwardTypes" table="award_types" catalog="mgs" optimistic-lock="version">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Byte">
            <column name="id" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="string">
            <column name="name" length="250" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="image" type="string">
            <column name="image" length="500" />
        </property>
        <property name="created" type="timestamp">
            <column name="created" length="19" />
        </property>
        <property name="modified" type="timestamp">
            <column name="modified" length="19" />
        </property>
        <set name="awardses" table="awards" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="award_type_id" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.mgs.Awards" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Configuration:

- Grails 3.0.9
- Domain objects reverse engineered from JBoss' Hibernate tools placed in /src/main/groovy/com/mgs/*
- CRUD code from `grails generate-all com.mgs.AwardTypes`
- MySQL 5.6
- Windows 7 Pro, Cygwin

I would have thought it would have been something like this:

```
class AwardTypesController {
       ...
       def edit(int id) {
            respond AwardTypes.get(id)
        }
        ...
    }
```

Comment: I believe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22099498/2051952) answers your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all due to [Data Binding](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#dataBinding), it's automatically done by Grails.

Answer (score 0):

You must add this code in **UrlMappings**.groovy :

```
class UrlMappings {
     static mappings = {
         .....
      "/awardTypes/edit/$id"(controller: "awardTypes", action: "edit")
     }
}
```

In your **Controller** 1.) :

```
def edit() {
    AwardTypes.get(params.id)
}
```

**or**

```
 def edit(Long id) {
    AwardTypes.get(id)
}
```

*Better use **Long** instead of **int**, because in grails it is default type for id.*

*In addition, I can show my UrlMapping:

```
class UrlMappings {

static mappings = {
    ...
    "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?" {
        constraints {
            // apply constraints here
        }
    }
    ....
   }
}
```

Also, read more : https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Plug-ins/URL%20mappings.html